# How to structure a MongoDB pipeline to sort by average

Tags: mongodb, pipeline

I'm trying to complete a pipeline with the following requirements:

Design and implement a pipeline to show the names, total number of funding rounds, and average amount of money raised from funding rounds
for companies that have funding rounds data, excluding those that do not. Show only the top 10 by average amount raised.

An example of the structure of the collection is shown below:

```
"name" : "Wetpaint",
"funding_rounds" : [
                {
                        "id" : 888,
                        "round_code" : "a",
                        "source_url" : "http://seattlepi.nwsource.com/business/246734_wiki02.html",
                        "source_description" : "",
                        "raised_amount" : 5250000,
                        "raised_currency_code" : "USD",
                        "funded_year" : 2005,
                        "funded_month" : 10
                        "funded_day" : 1,
                        "investments" : [
                                {
                                        "company" : null,
                                        "financial_org" : {
                                                "name" : "Frazier Technology Ventures",
                                                "permalink" : "frazier-technology-ventures"
                                        },
                                        "person" : null
                                },
                                {
                                        "company" : null,
                                        "financial_org" : {
                                                "name" : "Trinity Ventures",
                                                "permalink" : "trinity-ventures"
                                        },
                                        "person" : null
                                }
                        ]
                }, ...
```

I used some of the structures of similar pipeline designs, but it's not showing the total number of rounds and the order of the averages is incorrect.

```
db.research.aggregate([ 
    {$project: {"_id": 0, "name": 1, "funding_rounds": 1, "total_rounds":             
    {"$size":  "$funding_rounds"}}}, 
    {$match: {"total_rounds" : {"$gte" : 1}}}, 
    {$unwind: "$funding_rounds"}, 
    {$group: {"_id": "$name", "average": {"$avg": "$funding_rounds.raised_amount"}}}, 
    {$project: {"Name": "$_id", "_id": 0, "Total_funding_rounds": "$total_rounds", "Average_amount_raised": "$average"}},
    {$sort: {"average": -1}}, 
    {$limit: 10}
])
```

The results should be ordered by the average amount raised and exclude those without any funding rounds.

Expected:

```
{ "Name" : "Cameron Health", "Average_amount_raised" : 60500000 }
{ "Name" : "Luminus Devices", "Average_amount_raised" : 33956593.25 }
{ "Name" : "Nellix", "Average_amount_raised" : 6500000 }
{ "Name" : "Purfresh", "Average_amount_raised" : 6270000 }
{ "Name" : "Treehouse", "Average_amount_raised" : 4847049.25 }
{ "Name" : "SolarPower Israel", "Average_amount_raised" : 1100000 }
{ "Name" : "DocASAP", "Average_amount_raised" : 799998 }
{ "Name" : "Getyoo", "Average_amount_raised" : 376666.6666666667 }
```

Actual:

```
{ "Name" : "Nellix", "Average_amount_raised" : 6500000 }
{ "Name" : "Luminus Devices", "Average_amount_raised" : 33956593.25 }
{ "Name" : "Purfresh", "Average_amount_raised" : 6270000 }
{ "Name" : "Treehouse", "Average_amount_raised" : 4847049.25 }
{ "Name" : "SolarPower Israel", "Average_amount_raised" : 1100000 }
{ "Name" : "Getyoo", "Average_amount_raised" : 376666.6666666667 }
{ "Name" : "Embedster", "Average_amount_raised" : 0 }
{ "Name" : "EnteGreat", "Average_amount_raised" : 0 }
{ "Name" : "DocASAP", "Average_amount_raised" : 799998 }
{ "Name" : "Cameron Health", "Average_amount_raised" : 60500000 }
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```java
db.research.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "funding_rounds.0": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "total_rounds": {
                "$size": "$funding_rounds"
            },
            "name": "$name",
            "Average_amount_raised": {
                "$avg": "$funding_rounds.raised_amount"
            },
            "_id": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "Average_amount_raised": -1
        }
    }
])
```

you can see it working here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lq2q1ATfDzu

corresponding c# code:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Company : Entity
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public FundingRound[] funding_rounds { get; set; }
        }

        public class FundingRound
        {
            public int raised_amount { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            (new[] {
                new Company {
                    name = "Wet Paint",
                    funding_rounds = new[]
                    {
                        new FundingRound { raised_amount = 100},
                        new FundingRound { raised_amount = 100}
                    }
                }
            }).Save();

            var result = DB.Queryable<Company>()
                           .Where(c => c.funding_rounds.Count() > 0)
                           .Select(c => new
                           {
                               total_rounds = c.funding_rounds.Count(),
                               c.name,
                               Average_amount_raised = c.funding_rounds.Average(r => r.raised_amount)
                           })
                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Average_amount_raised)
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also, don't forget to [accept as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when someone solves your problems on the site. cheers!

Comment: "$avg" is a grouping operation. It won't work in "$project".

Comment: I need to find a way to prevent total_rounds from being lost once I unwind funding_rounds.

Comment: I think I've managed to make it better: db.research.aggregate([{$match: {"total_money_raised": {"$ne": "$0"}}}, {$project: {"_id": 0, "name": 1, "funding_rounds": 1, "total_rounds": {"$size":  "$funding_rounds"}}}, {$unwind: "$funding_rounds"}, {$group: {"_id": "$name", "average": {"$avg": "$funding_rounds.raised_amount"}}}, {$project: {"Name": "$_id", "_id": 0, "total_rounds": "$total_rounds", "Average_amount_raised": "$average"}}, {$sort: {"average": -1}}, {$limit: 10}])

Comment: @TracyHarrison sorry i missed that you needed total_rounds in the result because your expected output doesn't show it. i've updated my answer to include it. also $avg [does work](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#use-in-project-stage) inside $project. [here's proof](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lq2q1ATfDzu). so the query you've come up with is doing some unnecessary work which will reduce efficiency. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My final code looked like this:

```
db.research.aggregate([
{$match: {"total_money_raised": {"$ne": "$0"}}}, 
{$project: {"_id": 0, "name": 1, "funding_rounds": 1}}, 
{$unwind: "$funding_rounds"}, 
{$group: {"_id": "$name", "average": {"$avg": "$funding_rounds.raised_amount"}, "total_rounds": {"$sum": 1}}}, 
{$sort: {"average": -1}}, {$project: {"Name": "$_id", "_id": 0, "total_rounds": "$total_rounds", "Average_amount_raised": "$average"}}, 
{$limit:10}
])
```

Results:

```
{ "total_rounds" : 4, "Name" : "Clearwire", "Average_amount_raised" : 1425000000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 1, "Name" : "Terra-Gen Power", "Average_amount_raised" : 1200000000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 1, "Name" : "Xerox", "Average_amount_raised" : 1100000000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 1, "Name" : "Blackberry", "Average_amount_raised" : 1000000000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 1, "Name" : "AOL", "Average_amount_raised" : 1000000000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 1, "Name" : "Telefonica", "Average_amount_raised" : 743000000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 6, "Name" : "DeNA", "Average_amount_raised" : 736000000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 1, "Name" : "Comcast", "Average_amount_raised" : 725000000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 1, "Name" : "FriendFinder Networks", "Average_amount_raised" : 551200000 }
{ "total_rounds" : 2, "Name" : "Sirius XM Radio, Inc.", "Average_amount_raised" : 527875000 }
```